# Mysql for update

Tags: mysql, transactions, sql-update

MySQL supports "for update" keyword. Here is how I tested that it is working as expected. I opened 2 browser tabs and executed the following commands in one window.

```
mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from myxml where id = 2 for update;
....
mysql> update myxml set id = 3 where id = 2 limit 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> commit;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)
```

---

In another window, I started the transaction and tried to take an update lock on the same record.

```
mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from myxml where id = 2 for update;
Empty set (43.81 sec)
```

As you can see from the above example, I could not select the record for 43 seconds as the transaction was being processed by another application in the Window No 1. Once the transaction was over, I got to select the record, but since the id 2 was changed to id 3 by the transaction that was executed first, no record was returned.

My question is what are the disadvantages of using "for update" syntax? If I do not commit the transaction that is running in window 1 will the record be locked for-ever?

Comment: "disadvantages" that is very dependent on your requirements, can you please explain more what you need the locks for?

Comment: I have accepted answers to almost all the questions. You can check it if you want. Please stop asking people to work on something that is not possible :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if transaction #1 does not commit, those records will be locked forever, unless the connection drops, or innodb decides to rollback the transaction due to a deadlock detection.

> but since the id 2 was changed to id 3
>   by the transaction that was executed
>   first, no record was returned.

Isn't that what you want? if not, then you are not using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` properly. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. But I do not want the lock if the commit does not happen due to some reason, for e.g. user aborted the connection. Besides, is there a way to know how many records are locked for update at any given time?

Comment: @shantanuo If the user aborted the connection, the transaction will get rolled back automatically.

Comment: working with transactions you should handle the fact you have some waiting tasks. But you can change the timeout duration http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout